# Android Java can't find drawable inside XML File Button

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I developed my app on Android 23 (Marshmallow) with backward compatiblity to 19 (KitKat)

After providing my app to collegues I got response that Android 19 and 22 the app is always closing down.

I found that the following code generated the problem in 19 and 22 (23 is working like a charm):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Profile_Add"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_add_box_black_24dp"
    android:layout_width="150dp"          
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Profile_New"/>
```

It generated the failure:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/ic_add_box_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID xxxxxx

Removing the drawable part solved this button but stuck with the next button with drawable in the XML file.
I tried if the drawable is accessable with the following menue entry:

```
<item android:id="@+id/R_Test"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_box_black_24dp"
    android:title="Test"/>
```

This worked without problems.

Why is my code working with Android 6.0 but not with 4.4 and 5.1 ?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, but please just focus on asking your question. It takes longer for us to find your question and answer it otherwise

Comment: Are there different values folders? Like res/values and res/values-21?

Comment: Yes there are.
Values (including colors,dimens,strings,styles)

Comment: values (colors,dimens,strings,styles)
values-de(strings)
values-v21(styles >>missing Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar & ThemeOverlay...)
values-w820dp(dimens)

Answer (score -1):

I generated a new app with ic_add_box_black_24dp.xml in drawable and the mentioned button xml for Android 19. It worked without problems.
Comparing the build.gradle (Module:app) I found that

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

was not mentioned in the test app. After removing the line in my app it worked as expected.

Comment: this answer-feed is not for OP . If you missing something in ur question . you can use your  comment field..